# Probable bug in EdgeAdd when adding edges to multigraphs

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.1**

M10.0.2 and M10.3 return a wrong result without errors. M11.0 and M12.0 issue a flood of messages and sometimes crash.

---

I am using Mathematica 12.0, and the code

```
EdgeAdd[Graph@{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2]}, UndirectedEdge[1, 1]]
```

results in some weird error ("Take: Cannot take positions 1 through 4 in ..."). Adding edges to simple graphs seems to be OK, so

```
EdgeAdd[Graph@{UndirectedEdge[1, 2]}, UndirectedEdge[1, 1]]
```

works fine. Also there seems to be no issue with having multigraphs with self-loops

```
Graph@{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 1]}
```

so the resulting graph itself has no problems. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: It may also result in a crash, or a really weird result. In Mathematica 10.0.2 I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKXBz.png [Please report this to Wolfram Support.](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback)